# Adding relationship property on projection based on node property during collapse path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am looking for a way to add a relationship property to collapsed path during native projection. Eg. I'm collapsing `(P1)-[:HAS_ZIP]->(:ZIP)<-[:HAS_ZIP]-(P2)` to `(P1)-[:SHARES_ZIP]-(P2)`.

And I want to add say `[:SHARES_ZIP {verified: 1}]` if either P1/P2 have property is_verified=1 to use as weight in GDS centrality algorithms. I looked at the collapsePath [signature](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/beta-algorithms/collapse-path/) but couldn't find a way to add relationship properties.

Comment: The `collapsePath` function is still in the beta stage, you can use a normal cypher query to create the new relationship

Comment: Thanks, you mean directly in the db? Can you also suggest a way to optimize this Match bc looks like it traverses all nodes twice once from each side of the cypher and takes a long time to return: 

(P1)-[:HAS_ZIP]->(:ZIP)<-[:HAS_ZIP]-(P2)

Eg. P1 is traversed once from left and then again as P2 from right

Comment: Yes, I meant directly storing in the DB. To optimize the match you do `WHERE p1 <> p2` or compare some unique property, that will be more optimal

Comment: I did try the WHERE p1 <> p2 but it didn't help probably bc p1,p2 are different for the reverse traversal and I don't really have a unique property to filter because I'm creating a link bw all P nodes that share Zip

Comment: Got it, you can try this `MATCH (p1)-[:HAS_ZIP]->(z:ZIP) MATCH (p2)-[:HAS_ZIP]->(z) WHERE p1 <> p2`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is old but:

```
MATCH p=(P1)-[:HAS_ZIP]->(:ZIP)<-[:HAS_ZIP]-(P2)
WHERE NOT P1=P2 AND (P1.is_verified=1 OR P2.is_verified=1)

MERGE (P1)-[rel:SHARES_ZIP]-(P2)
SET rel.verififed=1 

RETURN p
```